# Banner scraper with phantomjs or pjscrape

Tags: javascript, web-services, screen-scraping, phantomjs

Would it be possible to develop a scraper with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) or [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) that would allow a user to enter a URL and pull all banner ads associated with that URL?

Comment: Yes it's possible but it's probably a lot easier to use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PhantomJS works well for this. It's a bit slow though, so we use some other techniques to crawl display ads at MixRank.